# SMS Forwarding or copying Problem

Tags: ubuntu-touch, sms

I cannot able copy nor forward the content of the SMS I received in my BQ Ubuntu Mobile. Could somebody knows how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to swipe the sms you want to forward to the left. There are 2 options: copy and info. You choose copy (the first one) and then you can paste the content into the new sms to forward.
I could not find a direct forward yet, but copy/ paste works as good.

Answer (score 1):

If you think forwarding should be supported you should open a feature request on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/messaging-app/+filebug